# Veeam Data Compression (File-level backup)

Tags: veeam

I’ve used Veeam Backup & Replication V10 solution; have ***File-level-backup*** jobs, ***Synthetic full backup***, local repo, and use ***Optimal*** Data Compression.

My issue is, ***High*** and ***Extreme*** Data Compression does not compress The Backup.

my backups took massive storage, why is the compression not working?

Comment: What kind of data are you backing up? Some data can't just be compressed anymore.

Comment: It's a massive Storage that have Normal files & Directories  (Excel, DWG, ...)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compress incompressible or pre-compressed data.

Depending on your setup, the OS or file system might already be compressing everything (e.g. deduplication on Windows servers).